# What is the difference between view.getId() and getResource.getIdentifier()

Tags: android, android-developer-api

I start learning Android Studio and encounter two ways to get the id for a resource, `getId()` and `getResource.getIdentifier()`.

But I did not understand the difference between both:

- I/do_no is output for getId()
- I/obj_no is output of getResource.getIdentifier().

```
2020-07-15 21:10:47.175 28459-28459/com.example.identifier I/id_no:: 131165281
2020-07-15 21:10:47.175 28459-28459/com.example.identifier I/obj_no:: 2131492864
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`view.getId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getId()) method returns the `android:id` value defined in the layout.
For example:

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
```

The [`getResources().getIdentifier()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method returns a resource identifier for the given resource name.

```
int resourcesId = getResources().getIdentifier("bottomAppBar", "id", getPackageName());
```

In this case the values are the same.

[image]

You can use the `getResources().getIdentifier()` to get all the resource ids.
For example in the `strings.xml` file

```
<string name="app_name">QuickSample</string>
```

You can use:

```
    int nameId = getResources().getIdentifier("app_name", "string",getPackageName());
    int nameAppNameId = R.string.app_name;
```

They are the same.